# What are the benefits of having a benevolent dictator for life (BDFL) on OSS?

Tags: contributor, project-management

I've seen a number of differing governance styles on open source projects. Some have looser contribution restrictions, with PR approval coming from people who have earned the privilege to do so, either through merit, election, or membership on the host foundation/corporation. Others have a single person with final say over the project, a so-called "benevolent dictator," usually the original creator/founder.

Are there benefits for contributors and users to participating in BDFL-led projects over more open governance models?

Comment: What are the benefits of other models? You seem to assume other models are better, but why? A founder can ensure that contributions are consistent and stay true to the original vision of the project - which presumably made it successful and interesting in the first place.

Comment: _nod_. To give an example of another project this works well for -- Clojure hewing closely to Rich Hickey's design, there's better composability between libraries written for it than there is in, say, the Scala world (which tries hard to support multiple models for native development, not just for interop as Clojure does, and so fragments its developers across those supported models).

Comment: @Polygnome: Well, one reason to suspect that other models can be better is that Guido van Rossum decided to stop being DBFL of Python.

Comment: @SteveJessop That might (merely) be an argument than being a BDFL is a hard job. You couldn't argue that Python hasn't been successful as a project before he quit, or that it isn't a respectable language.

Comment: A project needs an architect/captain.

Comment: @Steve Really? I'd say Guido's stewardship has helped Python become what it is today and made sure it's not a mess with a million conflicting features that someone somewhere once wanted. 
It's a thankless and hard job. Looking at the whole C++ mess as the classic example of design by committee (I'm sure there are others, but that's the one I'm aware of), I see definite advantages in having a BDFL over design by committee.

Comment: @Voo: my point is just that GvR, as BDFL, decided that Python was no longer working as well on that model as it would on a different model. So, either you accept his judgement as BDFL, or else you refuse to accept it. In which case, how can you support someone as BDFL whose judgement you don't accept any more? ;-) Sure, the model worked fine for a long time, but Polygnome is writing as if the questioner needs to make the case against dictatorship in order to ask this question. They don't: there are obvious reasons not to *assume* the BDFL model is perfect, but to inquire what's good about it.

Comment: Why is there need for any other model than BDFL (though most project leads do not actually call themselves "benevolent dictators")? It is open source; you always have the option to fork it to create your own version if you want to implement a change that is contrary to the founder's vision. Forking has gotten a bad name recently due to GitHub and due to derogatory labels such as "hostile fork," A fork simply means that you made some code that is derived from or similar to some other open source. At one time, Linux was considered a fork of Minix. Not anymore, of course.

Comment: @Steve That's not the case from all I've read on the mailing list. Guido stepped down because PEP 572 was a really unpleasant experience and he was "tired, and need a very long break". The BFDL model not working because Guido stepped down, is like saying democracy isn't working because a politician steps down. GvR also explicitly left the decision on how to continue running pyton-core to the core devs and let them decide on their preferred model (which I doubt will be a BFDL because you don't really elect those).

Comment: @Voo: So, to answer Polygnome's question using your answer, the benefit that GvR saw in a model other than BDFL, is that it prevents the BDFL crashing and burning and being too tired to do the job! Or, if you prefer, the benefit he saw in another model is that it could take over if and when the BDFL is unable to continue. You don't get to choose between "some other model" vs. "an immortal, untiring BDFL". You choose between "some other model" vs. "an actual BDFL". Guido chose to try something else.

Comment: ... He could have tried to hand over to a new or interim BDFL, or remained nominally as BDFL but delegate everything by fiat. Again, he chose not to try to maintain the BDFL model when he himself couldn't be the dictator. The core devs could unanimously nominate a new BDFL, if they think that model is so good that its benefits will still apply even when the BDFL is not the founder. As you say, they aren't showing strong signs of doing so!

Comment: @Steve The BFDL model certainly only works under certain circumstances. It's not for every project or every situation. The question is whether the BFDL model worked well for Python until now or not. And when comparing its development to say C++ (I remember an interview with Stroustrup where he said he hated a feature but had to add it to satisfy some committee members) my personal opinion is yes (I wouldn't begrudge you having a different opinion, although I'd like to hear an example where you think it failed).

Comment: I personally think the BFDL model only works for an original creator (I can't imagine electing a BFDL primus inter pares style would work particularly well socially) where that model is used from the start. Even then you need the right personality. But I find Python's development (or say Linux's) to work quite well compared to many other projects.

Comment: @Voo: well, the matter I'm addressing is Polygnome's utter incredulity at the notion that any model other than BDFL could have any benefits, and the explicit demand that the questioner must list pros on one side in order to ask what the pros are on the other side. One reason (among others) that this incredulous stance is absurd, is that *one actual BDFL* decided to change to a different system. In that context the fact that BDFL worked extremely well for Python in the past is not relevant: the BDFL eventually discovered circumstances where that model was worse than the alternative.

Comment: So, this fact about Python doesn't provide a reason to think other projects can't plan on using the BDFL model for, say, the first 30 years or so. It does suggest that the "FL" part of "BDFL" may not always be realistic, either the life of the project or the life of the dictator. Python's history of course provides ample material for answering the original question, *as well as* providing material for answering Polygnome's question about pros of other systems.

Comment: @Voo: "The BFDL model not working because Guido stepped down, is like saying democracy isn't working because a politician steps down." -- well, if you want an analogy to the governance of entire countries, then it's like saying *dictatorship* isn't working because a *dictator* steps down without a successor, and is replaced by something other than a new dictator. In a lot of contexts outside OSS, that would not be a particularly controversial conclusion about dictatorship! Ofc in practice national dictators rarely just "step down": GvR hardly faced trial in the event of losing power.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've always seen the BDFL model as halfway between a traditional open-source project structure and a traditional corporate project structure.  You have the openness, transparency, and general culture of OSS, but with a single strong project manager to make high-level decisions and direct the overall effort.

You can see many of the advantages just by breaking down the title itself:

- **Benevolent** - a mutual trust that this person will act in the project's best interest
- **Dictator** - this person is the singular, ultimate authority
- **For Life** - this person intends to lead the project for the long term, not just until something nicer comes along

A BDFL is highly invested in the project, typically the original creator. Their own name and professional reputation are often inseparable from that of the project. Unlike a corporate manager, users can find it easier to trust their leadership since the BDFL has a *highly* vested interest in the success and longevity of the project.  Both corporate projects and OSS projects can end up with a revolving door of leadership, which stalls progress and frustrates users. A BDFL generally holds that position for a long period of time (thus the "for life"), which adds a degree of stability to the project. It also allows leadership to develop and stick to a cohesive long-term vision instead of a series of short-lived leaders constantly changing plans and directions.

Frequently, a BDFL is also the undisputed subject matter expert and central authority for that particular project/technology. Corporate managers can run a project without a deep understanding of the technology or its history, leading to decisions that frustrate developers/users. Many OSS projects have a number of people in equally-powerful leadership roles, leaving room for disagreement and confusion.  If you have a question about where Python is heading and Guido van Rossum answers your question, then you can be confident that the answer is authoritative. BDFL-run projects tend to attract fewer forks for this reason. Any fork with only minor changes would seem like a "lesser" project without the BDFL's involvement. This helps prevent a community from splintering into multiple groups that are each too small to be effective.

Comment: "leaving room for disagreement and confusion" -- as part of this, a single technical authority can cut away a lot of bikeshedding on relatively unimportant decisions. Their preference becomes the decision, end of.

Answer (score 21):

I would say that projects having a BDFL **ultimately trust the vision of the project to one person**, as opposed to **design by committee**.

You can refer to [the list of BDFLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life).

Many of the individuals listed there have strong opinions as to what their respective project should do, not do, and how it should function (DHH and Theo are examples I am familiar with). Some others are not as controversial but are very respected in the community (Matz).

> Are there benefits for contributors and users to participating in BDFL-led projects over more open governance models?

If you are aligned with the BDFL in terms of vision for the project, contributing to a BDFL-run project makes sense. Alternatively, if you think that it is easier to evaluate a single person for trustworthiness (of project steering decisions) rather than a changing group of people, you may support the idea of a BDFL.